# Send message from my android app to whatsapp and reply with whatsapp back to my app

Tags: android, android-studio, message, whatsapp

I new to android development. I am building an app with a section that can send message from my app to a specific whatsapp number and the reply can be sent from whatsapp back to my app. Please is this Possible.

**I have read on sending messages from my app to whatsapp but seen nothing on replying from whatsapp back to my android app**

Am using Android Studio. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Second part of question is not possible .

Comment: @RishabhMaurya thanks a lot. Didn't find anything on the second part myself. Would try to see if i can build a chat app along with my app.

Answer (score 0):

The Whatsapp [documentation for integrating with android apps](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/28000012) says only 
about using an intent / URL scheme to trigger a pre-filled new message screen on Whatsapp. You'll need to manually click 'send' on Whatsapp screen nonetheless.

As far as 'receiving' goes, docs say nothing about that and frankly I doubt it is possible, just because Whatsapp doesn't provide such capability, as it would allow apps to eavesdrop on every message that's being sent to the app - major privacy/security issue.

Comment: thanks alot. Would try to see if i can build a chat app along side my app.